# Discarding part of view that goes out of layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-view

How to discard part of view in android that goes out of its layout boundaries,.let it be a video view, image view or any other view

[image]

In this image part of jelly fish image has gone out of its layout boundary.

I am creating relative layout at runtime and positioning images in layout based on x y coordinates.

Note: Layouts structure also changes at runtime

Comment: what do you mean by `discard`?

Comment: Use a frame layout... then you can place one view above the other.

Comment: Please brief you question more and also post some code or screenshot so that one can get the idea of your issue. @kapil

Comment: I have edited my question, can you please guide me

Answer (score 0):

1. Create custom layout with overridden onDraw(Canvas canvas)
2. canvas.clipRect(0, 0, mCanvasWidth, mCanvasHeight);

this will clip all views that goes out of layout boundary.

1. And don't forget to call setWillNotDraw(false); in constructor so your onDraw will execute